# Speed up getting edge matrix by index with numpy array

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix, indexing

I want to cut the edge in the original matrix and wonder is there a quicker way. Since I need to run selectEdge function many times with same positions and positions_u which means index would not change for many graphs? Is it possible to generate a mapping matrix that could fix for all?

thank you very much

```
def selectEdge(positions, positions_u, originalMat, selectedMat):
    """ select Edge by neighbors of all points
    many to many
    m positions
    n positions
    would have m*n edges
    update selectedMat
    """
    for ele in positions:
        for ele_u in positions_u:            
            selectedMat[ele][ele_u] += originalMat[ele][ele_u]
            selectedMat[ele_u][ele] += originalMat[ele_u][ele]
    return selectedMat
```

I only need the upper triangular matrix because it is symmetric

```
def test_selectEdge(self):
        positions, positions_u = np.array([0,1,5,7]), np.array([2,3,4,6])
        originalMat, selectedMat = np.array([[1.0]*8]*8), np.array([[0.0]*8]*8)
        selectedMat = selectEdge(positions, positions_u, originalMat, selectedMat)
        print 'position, positions_u'
        print positions, positions_u
        print 'originalMat', originalMat
        print 'selectedMat', selectedMat
```

here is my test results

```
position, positions_u
[0 1 5 7] [2 3 4 6]
originalMat 
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
selectedMat 
[[ 0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.]]
```

it would be even slower for latter implement of selecting neighbor edges

```
def selectNeighborEdges(originalMat, selectedMat, relation):
    """ select Edge by neighbors of all points
    one to many
    Args:
        relation: dict, {node1:[node i, node j,...], node2:[node i, node j, ...]}

    update selectedMat
    """
    for key in relation:
        selectedMat = selectEdge([key], relation[key], originalMat, selectedMat)
    return selectedMat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can eliminate the double `for-loop` by using ["advanced integer indexing"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing):

```
X, Y = positions[:,None], positions_u[None,:]
selectedMat[X, Y] += originalMat[X, Y]
selectedMat[Y, X] += originalMat[Y, X]
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np

def selectEdge(positions, positions_u, originalMat, selectedMat):
    for ele in positions:
        for ele_u in positions_u:
            selectedMat[ele][ele_u] += originalMat[ele][ele_u]
            selectedMat[ele_u][ele] += originalMat[ele_u][ele]
    return selectedMat

def alt_selectEdge(positions, positions_u, originalMat, selectedMat):
    X, Y = positions[:,None], positions_u[None,:]
    selectedMat[X, Y] += originalMat[X, Y]
    selectedMat[Y, X] += originalMat[Y, X]
    return selectedMat


N, M = 100, 50
positions = np.random.choice(np.arange(N), M, replace=False)
positions_u = np.random.choice(np.arange(N), M, replace=False)
originalMat = np.random.random((N, N))
selectedMat = np.zeros_like(originalMat)
```

First check that `selectEdge` and `alt_selectEdge` return the same result:

```
expected = selectEdge(positions, positions_u, originalMat, selectedMat)
result = alt_selectEdge(positions, positions_u, originalMat, selectedMat)
assert np.allclose(expected, result)
```

Here is a timeit benchmark (using IPython):

```
In [89]: %timeit selectEdge(positions, positions_u, originalMat, selectedMat)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.44 ms per loop

In [90]: %timeit alt_selectEdge(positions, positions_u, originalMat, selectedMat)
10000 loops, best of 3: 104 µs per loop
```